# Need my output to be in this form XXX.XXX c++

Tags: c++, math, formatting, significant-digits

for example im getting an area of 6 for a triangle, i need my output to show 006.000

i know setprecision will do the trick for limiting the decimal places to three but how do i place zeros in front of my solutions?

this is what i have

CTriangle Sides(3,4,5);

```
cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);

cout << "\n\n\t\tThe perimeter of this tringle is   = " << Sides.Perimeter();

cout << "\n\n\t\tThe area of the triangle is        = " << Sides.Area();

cout << "\n\n\t\tThe angle one is                   = " << Sides.Angleone();

cout << "\n\n\t\tThe angle two is                   = " << Sides.Angletwo();

cout << "\n\n\t\tThe angle three is                 = " << Sides.Anglethree();

cout << "\n\n\t\tThe altitude one of the triangle   = " << Sides.Altitudeone();

cout << "\n\n\t\tThe altitude two of the triangle   = " << Sides.Altitudetwo();

cout << "\n\n\t\tThe altitude three of the triangle = " << Sides.Altitudethree();
```

with the output being

```
            The perimeter of this triangle is   = 12.000

            The area of the triangle is        = 6.000

            The angle one is                   = 90.000

            The angle two is                   = 36.870

            The angle three is                 = 53.130

            The altitude one of the triangle   = 2.400

            The altitude two of the triangle   = 6.667

            The altitude three of the triangle = 3.750
```

but i need all the answers to be in this form XXX.XXX regardless of what my solutions are.(because the values will change)

any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use [padding](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) and [filling](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/) manipulators:

```
std::setfill('0');             // is persistent
//...

cout << std::setw(7) << value; // required for each output
```

Comment: remember to also set `fixed` and `precision`

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::internal`, `std::fixed`, `std::setfill`, `std::setw` and `std::setprecision` from [iomanip](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) and related headers, you can do:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setfill('0') << std::internal << std::setprecision(3);

std::cout << std::setw(7);
std::cout << 12.34f << "\n";
```

and get the desired output. [See it live on Coliru!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ea6ae9fc6fb9fb8)

Answer (score 1):

See "format": [String and I/O Formatting (Modern C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438469.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The printf function can do that for you have a look at the docs: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Your case is somewhat unique because:
(these are not complete code snippets, apologies)

precision only applies to floating point formatting:

```
$ printf("%03.3f\n", 6)
> 6.000
```

And left padding only applies to integer formatting:

```
$ printf("%03.3d\n", 6)
> 006
```

Good luck hopefully you can take it from here

Comment: `printf` function comes from C, and though avaliable, it's considered bad to mix with C++.

Comment: "considered bad" - more specifically, they're buffered independently, so you need to explicitly flush each time you switch between writing some stuff using `printf()` and writing to `std::cout`.  +1 anyway - this can be convenient, and [boost format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/) uses vaguely `printf`-like notation for convenient formatting in a more C++-aware way.